# RestSharp request working in Postman but not C# (0kb file)

Tags: c#, postman, multipartform-data, restsharp, jira-rest-api

My other RestSharp code is working just fine, I am making about 10 other POSTS and GETS and PUTS without a problem.  But this request will not work correctly for some reason.  My file is attaching to the Jira ticket, however, it is 0kb and it will not open.

I think it has something to do with the multi-part file I am POSTing, but this is the code I am getting directly from Postman which works there, but not working here.

```
var client = new 
RestClient("https://HOST.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/SS-1289/attachments");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "asd238-c5cd-4bb8-6546-01f0asd00cb");

request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRhbS5hbGtvdpISVZ4MDNmZlBnN0VENw==");

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");

request.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"FUSION.docx ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\"");

request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

request.AddHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");

request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");

request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"C:\\temp\\FUSION.docx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Anyone have any clue why this isn't working?

Comment: http://restsharp.org/ - search the page for `AddFile`. That is the bit you aren't doing.

Comment: I tried getting addfile to work, just could not.  I don't see many examples online either.   Any other suggestions?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could update your post to show your attempt.

Comment: Basically the same thing but I added:

request.AddFile("content.jpg",path);

Nothing new happens when I add this.

Comment: Any solution to this? Got the same problem